# Expand list using list of booleans

Tags: python

I have a list with N elements and a list of booleans with N Trues

```
a = [10,200]
ind = [False, True, False, True, False]
```

i would like to place the elements of **a** into a list **b** using **ind** as index, which result in

```
b = [0, 10, 0, 200, 0]
```

Is there a way to do so in an efficient and easily-readable way?

The best way I could achieve this is doing

```
positions = [i for (i,test) in zip(range(len(i)),i) if test]
for i in range(len(positions)):
    b[position[i]] = a[i]
```

but that looks a bit overcomplicated to me

Comment: I'm a beginner in python and still not too familiar with the slicing process. I found a couple of ways to do it with a for cycle and generating a couple of temporary variables, but that looks overcomplicated to me.

And I don't understand why this question is down-voted? Too trivial?

Comment: It's downvoted because you have made no effort.  It's awesome that you're learning python, but *since* you are trying to learn you should make an attempt on your own before you ask questions here, and include that attempt in your question to show others that you have tried.  If you edit your attempts in your question, it's actually a pretty interesting problem that people would be happy to answer.

Comment: @LucaAmerio 
You get downvotes because you have not shown what you have tried, although the code you have does not work the same you have to place it but we assume that you want us to do your work, read [ask] and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/.

Comment: @LucaAmerio do not use `zip(range(len(i)),i)` but `enumerate(i)`

Comment: @chrisz get your point, but in the context of stackoverflow where even starting the question with "Hi" is considered a waste of space/time/resources, having to "prove" that I did my homeworks looks exceedingly silly. I have a 10 years experience with Matlab and I'm migrating to Python. Having to prove that I'm not lazy is almost an insult... Anyway... if these are the rules I'll stick to them

Comment: @LucaAmerio. What should the output be if there are more `True` elements in `ind` than there are elements in `a`?

Comment: @ekhumoro Due to how the code is done, that is impossible

Comment: @LucaAmerio 
In SO nobody tries to insult you, asking you to show what you have tried does not imply that. Here we work with what they propose, it is better that you learn from your mistakes, that enriches the question and improves the answers. You can have n-years with a language but it does not imply that you are good with another. So we recommend that you show your intent when necessary, and read the links that we have shown you so you can better understand how SO works. 
It is easier for you to adapt to the community, for the community to adapt to you. :D

Comment: Your questions are judged by quality period, and we vote on *question* quality only, not on perceived asker quality or effort. Those questions that show an attempt and use the attempt to make the question more specific and less of one answered by, "you want to read the tutorial on..." are plainly better questions.

Comment: If you want to do something "easily-readable", which is a good idea, _don't use booleans as integers_, ever. It is true that `1 == True` and `0 == False`, but write your code as if that was not true. If you want indexes, use 1 and 0.

Comment: @zvone isn't it exactly what I've done in this code?

Comment: I'm not talking about your code, I'm talking about your question: _"using ind as index"_, where `ind = [False, True, False, True, False]`. There is no nice solution to a bad task. Why do you have `ind = [False, True, False, True, False]` in the first place and not `ind = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]`? I'm saying change something in the step which comes before that.

Comment: @zvone I have a list of objects. I need to apply a function to them that can be time-consuming. However for most of them (99%) I can perform a logical test that will tell me in advance if the result will be zero. What I'm doing is therefore: perform the test, extract the index of those that will return non-zero values, slice them, perform the operation on them, build the output value putting the non-zero values in the correct places. The "ind" is therefore the output of the logic test. Was the task easier if ind = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]?

Comment: I guess i misunderstood, because the variable name is misleading... Those are not really indices in ind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `N` elements, and `N` `True`'s in your list, using an iterator works great here.  You can use the [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function to convert your list to an iterator.

```
a = iter([10,200])
ind = [False, True, False, True, False]
```

Now you can get your desired result using a simple list comprehension.  This list comprehension will replace `True` with the next value in your iterator, and will replace `False` with 0:

```
final = [next(a) if i else 0 for i in ind]
```

Which results in:

```
[0, 10, 0, 200, 0]
```

Calling `next(a)` will keep grabbing values from your iterator at which point it will raise a `StopIteration` exception.  However, since you have an equal number of elements and `True`'s, this exception will not occur.